# Global change applied only to lists inside definition and theorem environments

Tags: enumitem, grouping

For editing my lecture notes and worksheets, I am using the enumitem package. I regularly make global changes, for example using the following code in the preamble:

```
\setenumerate[1]{label={\bfseries\arabic*)}}
\setenumerate[2]{label={\bfseries\alph*.},nosep}
```

But now I would like to modify the lists only inside already defined environments, such as the definition and theorem environments. Of course, I can always make changes whenever needed:

```
\begin{definitions}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=!,labelsep=1ex,labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=2.5ex,itemindent=3.5ex,label={\bfseries\arabic*.}]
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{definitions}
```

But how may I avoid having to copy and paste these lines of code systematically?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

With a current latex you could use the generic environment hook

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\AddToHook{env/quote/begin}{\setenumerate[1]{label={\bfseries \arabic*)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}

\begin{quote}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{quote}

\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the advantages of \AddToHook compared to the other solution proposed below?

Comment: LaTeX hooks can be labeled, ordered and removed by such a label. And beside this, in a current LaTeX \AtBeginEnvironment is only a wrapper around the hook:`\newcommand\AtBeginEnvironment[2][.]    {\AddToHook{env/#2/begin}[#1]}`

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not seem to work on the Overleaf site. When did this label date?

Comment: the hooks has been added in latex 2020-10-01. If your latex is older you will have to use \AtBeginEnvironment (and probably have to load etoolbox).

Comment: It is indeed very, very recent. The version of Latex installed on my personal computer is older and would need to be updated, but the problem is that we don't have the ability to update the version used on Overleaf. In any case, thank you for all these explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Loading `enumitem`, you can use

`\AtBeginEnvironment{definitions}{\setlist[enumerate,1]{…} \setlist[enumerate,2]{…}}`

and similarly for the other environments.

Comment: This solution suits me perfectly. Thank you so much.